# Generate SHA-256 passwords with MariaDB

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I need to replace some plain text passwords with **SHA256 Base64** passwords.
Apparentely the hash generated by the database functions does not match with the ones used by the application. For example: my application uses this function for generating the hash:

```
$ echo -n "admin" | openssl dgst -sha256 -binary | openssl base64
jGl25bVBBBW96Qi9Te4V37Fnqchz/Eu4qB9vKrRIqRg=
```

Now, the same password with the database:

```
select TO_BASE64(SHA2('admin',256));
OGM2OTc2ZTViNTQxMDQxNWJkZTkwOGJkNGRlZTE1ZGZiMTY3YTljODczZmM0YmI4YTgxZjZmMmFiNDQ4YTkxOA==
```

As you can see it does not match! Any help ? 
My DB Version: Server version: 10.0.23-MariaDB MariaDB Server

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove **-binary** from `echo -n "admin" | openssl dgst -sha256 -binary | openssl base64` and you will get the same results.

with `-binary` it returns the actual binary data of the sha256 string, if thats what you want, you have to convert result from `SHA2('admin',256)` to binary and then apply `TO_BASE64` to it.

Comment: The exact query to get the hash you want is select TO_BASE64(UNHEX(SHA2('admin',256))) This answer gives a little more info on how SHA2 works http://stackoverflow.com/a/22121627/947240

Answer (score 1):

```
echo -n "admin" | openssl dgst -sha256 | awk '{ print $2; }' | openssl base64
```